# What is the difference between Stoicism's logos and Zhu Xi's li (理)?

Tags: confucius

What is the difference between Stoicism's *logos* (reason) and Zhu Xi's *li* (理)?

In stoicism, the universe/cosmos/nature is organized according to *logos* (reason). With *logike*, the individual can grasp reason, and following it, live according to nature.

In Zhu Xi's thought, the cosmos, and everything and everyone, is made of *li* (理) and *qi* (氣), which operate together in mutual dependence.

*Qi* (氣) is translated as "vital", "physical", "material".

To what I understand, the human nature is inherently good, and everyone's *li* (理) is good, which translates into a perfect moral nature, or *xing* (性). Therefore, everyone should act morally.

It is the *qi* (氣) which can cause immoral behavior. This mental imperfection can be corrected through the study of ethics and metaphysics.

The ethics in confucianism is famously inter-personal (humaneness (*ren* 仁, “benevolence” or “Goodness”), righteousness (*yi* 義), ritual propriety (*li* 禮, sometimes simply “propriety”), wisdom (*zhi* 智), and faithfulness (*xin* 信)).

But *li* (理) is translated by "pattern", "rational principle", "law", "organisational rights". It is not translated by "logic" (in contemporary Chinese language, 理 in fact means "reason"/"logic", but in the scientific documentation commenting on Zhu Xi's *li* (理), it is not translated this way).

On the other hand, I can read here and there that Zhu Xi's school, because of this concept of *li* (理), is to be comparable to rationalism, or that Zhu Xi insisted on logic.

It seems to me clear that *logike*, is something really similar, or identical, to modern logic. But I am less sure for *li* (理).

Also, it seems that the idea of stoicism is to follow reason to understand the world and find one's place in it, but apparently in Zhu Xi's thought, we need to follow ethics (although, again, he seems to also insist on logic, but I don't know to what it corresponds in his thought then).

Comment: From my limited Chinese understanding the word 理 really means 'the king *inside*', and 'king' insinuates this noumena thing-in-itself stuff *dictates* all its phenomenal outside. Thus it could be more accurately linked to Aristotle's in-re forms of his hylomorphism compared to Stoic's logos supposed to be some pneumatic rationality space/sky permeates and emanates the whole universe...